# Getting a line from a word document using Selection object (vba)

Tags: vba

How can i get a line from a word document using the Selection object in VBA script? Something like this:

```
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=15
'print the 15th line here
```

EDIT: When i do:

```
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=15
MsgBox (Selection.Text)
```

It prints only the first character of the line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to expand the selection:

```
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=15
Selection.Expand wdLine
MsgBox (Selection.Text)
```